# Multiple camera view triangulation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, numerical-methods, camera-calibration

Given a scene, multiple camera views of that scene and their corresponding projection matrices, we wish to triangulate 2D matching points into 3D.
What i've been doing so far is solve the system *PX = alphax* where P is the projection matrix, X is the 3D point in camera coordinates, alpha is a scalar and x is the vector corresponding to the point in 2D. X and x are in homogeneous coords.
See https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/handle/1807/10437 page 102 for more detail.

Solving this with an SVD yields proper results when the 2D points are accurately selected or when i only use two views. Introducing more views adds a lot of error.

Any advice on what techniques are best to improve/refine this solution and make it support more views?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, we can view this as finding a point in 3D space that minimizes the sum of orthogonal distances between the point and lines (one line per camera view) ? I guess with a gradient descent in 3d space, it's possible to find a local minimum of this.

Did I understand the problem correctly?

Comment: The problem would rather be finding the point that minimizes reprojected errors, meaning that when you take the 3D point and project it back on each view, it should be closest to all initial 2D markers.

Comment: Ok, then the cost function used in the gradient descent should be updated w.r.t my answer (cost = sum of reprojected errors). I think 3D gradient descent is a valid approach here. What do you think?